# Is there any code provider for C++ in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, c++, csharpcodeprovider, vbcodeprovider

I used below codes as code provider for C# and VB.net

```
var codeProvider = new VBCodeProvider();
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
```

Like that, Is there any code provider available for C++ in visual studio 2012

Comment: Yes there is [but only for managed C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualc.cppcodeprovider(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Mgetz - Is it available for .net 4.5 version

Comment: No not that I'm aware of, Managed C++ has always been the outcast of .Net languages.

Answer (score 0):

The [C/C++ implementation of CodeDomProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualc.cppcodeprovider%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is not available in .net 4 or 4.5, you can tell from the inheritance hierarchy they now provide on MSDN [see CodeDomProvider here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I don't know why that is though.